# Unable to add entitlement on Xcode 5 with multiple developer accounts

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

I have multiple developer accounts registered on my Mac, the first one being my personal, and the rest the people/companies that I work with/for. I am trying to add an In-app purchase entitlement to one of the projects and I'm getting `An app ID with identifier 'com.XXX.XXX' [I have my correct bundle ID there] is not available. Please enter a different string.` error. The first time I've tried to add, I got an error about my personal developer account (that isn't tied to the app that I'm working on) not having that app (which is true). How can I add the entitlement from Xcode (other than manually editing, obviously)?

Comment: Entitlements is matched to the provisioning profile, try to select the profile manually. To make the identifier value to match the selected profile, use `$(AppIdentifierPrefix).com.my.app.id` instead of hardcoded prefixes.

Comment: your comment signaled a red light in my head. I've gone to the "General" section and I've realized that the incorrect team (my personal one instead of my company's one) was selected. I've selected the correct Team and it worked. the credit goes to you.. please post checking teams/profiles as an answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: Ok, I didn't even know there's such an option, not sure how it works exactly - you still can chose profiles from the other teams when you have selected a specific Team.

Comment: It's under Target's identity tab, under Bundle identifier, Version, and Build, there is Team option. Not sure if it's displayed if there is only one team on machine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the correct provisioning profile is selected (manually or automatically).